# Internet explorer keeps alerting with location.reload(); and POST data

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, post

After my form is confirmed theres a javascript overlay. If you close it the button triggers:

```
location.reload();
```

So the page is reloaded and my confirm page shows the updated database. This is perfect and what i want. BUT in Internet Explorer it keeps alerting something like "the inserted information need to be sent again [repeat] [cancel]".
If you hit repeat the "second popup, that you already signed up" is popping up everytime.

Nevermind if you hit cancel its ok. Is there a way to prevent Explorer to open this alert POST-alert ?

after confirm i already do this at the end of my PHP but it seems not do work:

```
unset($_POST);
```

Comment: That's a default browser's behaviour when reloading after a POST

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
window.location.href = window.location.search;
```

Comment: Using window.location.href will garantee that the solution works in all browsers.